# Determine how a user got to 403 page

Tags: c#, .net, http-status-code-403, custom-errors

My web.config is currently set up like so:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="500.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="403.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Is there any way to figure out from what url a user got redirected to the 403 from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at HttpRequest.UrlReferrer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there's a bug on my login page.